# Jenkins Pipeline - How to copy artifacts to remote location

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifact-deployer

I'm currently in the process of converting a freestyle job to a pipeline and have a build step that uses the ArtifactDeployer to deploy files from one directory to a remote location.

The ArtifactDeployer plugin on my freestyle job only has couple of fields set, 'Artifacts to deploy' and 'Remote File Location'.

What's the equivalent plugin I should be using that has pipeline support?

Comment: I haven't found any equivalent pipeline step (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/). 

In August 2016, someone opened an issue in Jira to add support for this plugin in pipelines (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37503?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20artifactdeployer-plugin).

So I guess you have to come up with your own solution. You can use "scp" command on Linux or Maven as suggested in that Jira issue...

Comment: I have since found I can achieve what I need with the stash\unstash command. I needed to stash a certain directory whilst on my master node and then unstash to a directory on a different node